How to find the computed distortion parameters in Blender
I just did a camera solve in Blender, and I'm going to do some compositing in Fusion.
I asked Blender to solve for Radial Distortion:

Is there a way that I can get the value of the coefficient used to undistort my footage?
Thanks!
Anson
